# Is there a possibility to glow the led in 5*5 matrix in a square shape with the common anode configuration

Tags: c, arduino, ide

I have a led-matrix that is common anode in row-wise and common cathode in column-wise. I need to glow the matrix in the shape of a square(first row && last row && first column && last column) , but I was not able to do it. I was able to glow the first and last row separately and first and second column separately)

```
void first_last_row();
void first_last_column();

int Led_Row_Pins[] = { 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 } ;             //   Anode pins are shorted in row_wise_manner
int Led_Column_Pins[] = {8  , 9 , 10 , 11 , 12} ;          //   Column Pins are shorted in column_wise_manner   
int Loop_Count = 5 ;
int Wait_Time_On = 1000 ;
int Wait_Time_Off = 500 ;
int i = 0 ;
int j = 0 ;
int state = 1 ;

void setup() {
  for( i = 0 ; i < Loop_Count ; i++ ){     // Anode Pins are connected in row_wise manner and are made LOW so that they dont conduct       
    pinMode(Led_Row_Pins[i],OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(Led_Row_Pins[i],LOW);
    pinMode(Led_Column_Pins[i],OUTPUT);    // Cathode Pins are connected in column_wise manner and are made HIGH so that they dont conduct
    digitalWrite(Led_Column_Pins[i],HIGH); 
  }
}

void loop() { 
      first_last_row();
      delay(1000);
      first_last_column();
}


void first_last_row()
{
  for( i = 0 ; i < Loop_Count ; i++ )// Led First And Last Row 
   {
     for( j = 0 ; j < Loop_Count ; j++)
     {
       if( i == 0 || i == 4 )
       {
         digitalWrite(Led_Row_Pins[i],state); //Led_On_State
         digitalWrite(Led_Column_Pins[j],!state);
       }
     }
   }
}


void first_last_column()
{

  for( j = 0 ; j < Loop_Count ; j++ )// Led First And Last Column
   {
     for( i = 0 ; i < Loop_Count ; i++)
     {
       if( j == 0 || j == 4 )
       {
        digitalWrite(Led_Row_Pins[i],state);//    Led_On_State
        digitalWrite(Led_Column_Pins[j],!state);
       }
     }
   }
}
```

I need the first row and the last row and first column and last column led glow together so that it forms the shape of a square but I was able to glow them separately only first row and last row together and first column and last  column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your specific case you could switch on the first and last row for e.g. 1msec then switch on the first and last column for 1msec and repeat this. I further suggest to switch off all LEDs before switching on a new pattern.

```
void loop() { 
      static int show_rows = 0;

      switch_all_off();
      if(show_rows) {
          first_last_row();
      } else {
          first_last_column();
      }
      show_rows = !show_rows;
      delay(10);
}

void switch_all_off()
{
    int off = 0;
    for( j = 0 ; j < Loop_Count ; j++ )
    {
          digitalWrite(Led_Row_Pins[i],off);
          digitalWrite(Led_Column_Pins[j],!off);
    }
}
```

With this first step the LEDs that are contained both in the rows and in the columns will be brighter. To fix this you can exclude the corner LEDs either from the rows or from the columns, e.g.

```
void first_last_column()
{

    for( j = 0 ; j < Loop_Count ; j++ )// Led First And Last Column
    {
        for( i = 0 ; i < Loop_Count ; i++)
        {
            if((i != 0) && (i != 4) && ( j == 0 || j == 4 ))
            {
                digitalWrite(Led_Row_Pins[i],state);//    Led_On_State
                digitalWrite(Led_Column_Pins[j],!state);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For a more general solution you have to loop over the rows, activate one row after the other and switch the column pins as necessary for the current row.

```
#define MAXLEDS 5
int states[MAXLEDS][MAXLEDS] = {
    { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
    { 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 },
    { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 }
};

void switch_leds(int row) {
    int i;

    /* switch off all rows */
    for(i = 0; i < MAXLEDS, i++) {
        digitalWrite(Led_Row_Pins[i], 0);
    }

    /* switch columns according to current row */
    for(i = 0; i < MAXLEDS; i++) {
        digitalWrite(Led_Column_Pins[i], !states[row][i]);
    }

    /* switch on current row */
    digitalWrite(Led_Row_Pins[row], 1);

}

void loop() { 
    static int row = 0;
    /* switch on LEDs in a single row */
    switch_leds(row);
    /* next row */
    row++; row %= MAXLEDS;
    /* The processing delay between calls to loop() is added to this delay. */
    delay(5);
}
```

All code examples are untested and may contain errors.

Comment: Sir, Thank you so much for your support the code is working fine, without your help, I would not have completed the task . Thank you.

Comment: @PaulsonRajaL If it works you can accept the answer.