# How to control the Led's in a 5*5 Led - Matrix with the help of 5*5 push-button

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, atmega, arduino-c++

I want two Led's ( Led 1 and Led 3 ) in a 5*5 Led - Matrix to light up and when the corresponding buttons in the 5*5 push-button are pressed the Led's turns off and another two Led's ( Led 3 and Led 5 ) should light up 
and when the corresponding buttons are pressed the Led's turns off and another two led's ( Led 5 and Led 11 ) should light up and the process continues for next set of Led's ( Led 11 and Led 13 ) and the next set is ( Led 13 and Led 15 ) and the next set is ( Led 15 and Led 17 ) and ( Led 17 and Led 21 ) and (Led 21 and Led 23 ) and ( Led 23 and Led 25 ).

The code I have written is :

```
/*  If both "first_key_pressed" and "second_key_pressed", we will make the next two LEDs glow and set these two values to zero again
    Initially, LEDs 1 and 3 are glowing, so it is declared that the Led 1 is currently first_in_position and Led 3 is currently second_in_position.
    Once 1 and 3 are pressed, we will change this two values to first_in_position = '3' and second_in_position = '5'
    The method set_next_expected_leds does this job.
*/


#include <Keypad.h>

const byte rows = 5; 
const byte cols = 5; 

char keys[rows][cols] = {
  {'1','2','3','4','5'},
  {'6','7','8','9','A'},
  {'B','C','D','E','F'},
  {'G','H','I','J','K'},
  {'L','M','N','O','P'}
};

byte rowPins[rows] = {40, 39 , 38 , 37 , 36 }; 
byte colPins[cols] = { 35 , 34 ,33 , 32 , 31 }; 

Keypad keypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, rows, cols );

int Led_Rows[] = { 2 , 3 , 4  ,5 ,6 } ;
int Led_Columns[] = { 7 , 8 , 9 , 10 , 11 };
int Loop_Count = 5 ;
int first_key_pressed = 0;
int second_key_pressed = 0;
char first_in_position = '1';
char second_in_position = '3';
int Wait_Time = 1000 ; 
int i = 0 ;
int j = 0 ;
int x = 0 ;
int y = 0 ; 
int c = 0 ;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    pinMode(Led_Rows[i], OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(Led_Rows[i],LOW);
    pinMode(Led_Columns[i], OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(Led_Columns[i],HIGH);
  }
  Led_Glow(0,0);
  Led_Glow(0,2);
}


void All_On(){
 for( i = 0  ; i < Loop_Count  ; i++ ){
    digitalWrite(Led_Rows[i],HIGH);
    while( j < Loop_Count ){
    digitalWrite(Led_Columns[j],LOW);
    j++ ;
    }
  }
  j = 0 ;
}

void All_Off(){
  for(  i = 0 ; i < Loop_Count ; i++ ){
    digitalWrite(Led_Rows[i],LOW);
    digitalWrite(Led_Columns[i],HIGH);
  }
}

void Led_Glow( int a , int b ){
  digitalWrite(Led_Rows[a],HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Led_Columns[b],LOW); 
}

void Led_Dim( int a ,int b ){
  digitalWrite(Led_Rows[a],LOW);
  digitalWrite(Led_Columns[b],HIGH);
}


void check_for_position(int c) {
  if (first_in_position == c) {
    first_key_pressed = 1;
  } else if (second_in_position == c) {
    second_key_pressed = 1;
  }
}

void set_next_expected_leds() {
  if (first_in_position == '1') {
    first_in_position = '3';
    second_in_position = '5';
    Led_Glow(0,2);
    Led_Glow(0,4);
  } else if (first_in_position == '3') {
    first_in_position = '5';
    second_in_position = 'B';
    Led_Glow(0,4);
    Led_Glow(2,0);
  } else if (first_in_position == '5') {
    first_in_position = 'B';
    second_in_position = 'D';
    Led_Glow(2,0);
    Led_Glow(2,2);
  } else if (first_in_position == 'B') {
    first_in_position = 'D';
    second_in_position = 'F';
    Led_Glow(2,2);
    Led_Glow(2,4);
  } else if (first_in_position == 'D') {
    first_in_position = 'F';
    second_in_position = 'L';
    Led_Glow(2,4);
    Led_Glow(4,0);
  } else if (first_in_position == 'F') {
    first_in_position = 'L';
    second_in_position = 'N';
    Led_Glow(4,0);
    Led_Glow(4,2);
  } else if (first_in_position == 'L') {
    first_in_position = 'N';
    second_in_position = 'P';
    Led_Glow(4,2);
    Led_Glow(4,4);
  } else if (first_in_position == 'N') {

  } else if (first_in_position == 'P') {

  }

  first_key_pressed = 0;
  second_key_pressed = 0;
}

void loop() { 
  char key = keypad.getKey();
   switch (key) {
    case '1':
      check_for_position('1');
      Led_Dim(0, 0);
      break;

    case '3':
      check_for_position('3');
      Led_Dim(0, 2);
      break;

    case '5':
      check_for_position('5');
      Led_Dim(0, 4);
      break;

    case 'B':
      check_for_position('B');
      Led_Dim(2, 0);
      break;

    case 'D':
      check_for_position('D');
      Led_Dim(2, 2);
      break;

    case 'F':
      check_for_position('F');
      Led_Dim(2, 4);
      break;

    case 'L':
      check_for_position('L');
      Led_Dim(4, 0);
      break;

    case 'N':
      check_for_position('N');
      Led_Dim(4, 2);

      break;

    case 'P':
      check_for_position('P');
      Led_Dim(4, 4);
    }
   if(first_key_pressed == 1 && second_key_pressed == 1) {
    set_next_expected_leds();
  }
}
```

Expected Result: The user can press button 1 or button 3 in the first step if he presses button 1 the led-1 should go off and after pressing button 3 the led-3 should go off and another set of LEDs (Led-3 and Led-5) should glow.

NOTE: The user has the right to press button-3 first and then button-1 then also first led-3 should go off and then led-1 should go off and then the next set of LEDs can glow.

Actual Result: If I press button 1 both led-1 and led-3 goes off and also when I press Button-3 some random led's start blinking.

Comment: provide your schematics. reduce your problem to a minimum. break it down into atomic steps and solve one by one rather than trying to get everything working in one go

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a possibility to glow the led in 5\*5 matrix in a square shape with the common anode configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58521030/is-there-a-possibility-to-glow-the-led-in-55-matrix-in-a-square-shape-with-the)